# how to align angular tag contents in span

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to align both information i.e PO number and Vendor properly, how to do it?

```
from

PO Number: 344 Vendor: yu
PO Number: 3445 Vendor: yu
PO Number: 344 Vendor: yu

to

PO Number: 344   Vendor: yu
PO Number: 3445  Vendor: yu
PO Number: 344   Vendor: yu
```

```
<div *ngFor="let n of listof_POs" style="color: white;">
      <span><b>PO Number: {{n.po_number}} &nbsp; &nbsp;Vendor: {{n.vendorname}} </b></s
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Angular Flex Layout, you can handle it like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let n of listof_POs" style="color: white;" fxLayout="row">
      <b fxFlex="50%">PO Number: {{n.po_number}}</b>
      <b fxFlex="50%">Vendor: {{n.vendorname}}</b>
</div>


You can also use CSS Flexbox to achieve this
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to create a table in a really difficult way why not try something like the following: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="n in listof_POs">
  <td>PO Number: {{ n.po_number}}</td>
  <td>Vendor {{ n.vendorname}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```